# extension name not being displayed as it is supposed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome-extension

In this extension, I was trying to make it say Hello and then the user's name. However, it continues to say the default which is Hello World and never says the user's name. I don't know if the JQuery is messed up but something is wrong.

Here is the html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

    <title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src='popup.js'>    
    </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js">    
    </script>

    <h2 id='greet'>Hello World!</h2>

    <input type="text" id='name'>    


</body>
</html>
```

Here is the Javascript:

```
$(function(){
    $('#name').keyup(function(){
        $('#greet').text('Hello ' + $('#name').val());
    })
});
```

Comment: Seems likely that there is an error in popup.js (or elsewhere) that is preventing this script from running - the script you posted works fine

Comment: Try debugging. https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tut_debugging

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is just fine, however change the order of jQuery and your own script, since it can't run it because there is no jQuery at that point to run. HTML reads its documents from top to bottom, in a linear fashion. That's why it dosn't work.

```js
$(function(){
    $('#name').keyup(function(){
        $('#greet').text('Hello ' + $('#name').val());
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id='greet'>Hello World!</h2>

    <input type="text" id='name'>
```

Comment: Note that an extension context will not load jQuery from an external CDN unless [CSP is overridden](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#relaxing-remote-script). In general, it's a bad idea _not_ to pack such resources with the extension.